# Coding problem about post notification on android

Tags: android

> I need to Rewrite all the deprecated methods and class.

```
private void showNotification(Peer peer, int id) {
    CharSequence text = getString(id) + " " + peer.getName();
    Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.notification, text, System.currentTimeMillis());

    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL; 

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, IPsecToolsActivity.class); //intent.setAction(ACTION_NOTIFICATION);

    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);

    notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, getText(R.string.native_service_label), text, contentIntent);    //setLatestEventInfo method has been deprecated

    // Send the notification.
    mNM.notify(peer.getName(), R.string.notify_peer_up, notification);
}
```

> **Note that the Notification is deprecated**, too old.
>   Cannot use setLatestEventInfo method.
>   I need help rewrite it in alternative way.

The way I rewrite this is as following: Please let me know if I was right or not.

```
private void showNotification(Peer peer, int id) {
    CharSequence text = getString(id) + " " + peer.getName();

    Context context = this; 
    Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(context)    
            .setContentText(text)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification)
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
            .build();


    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, IPsecToolsActivity.class);
    //intent.setAction(ACTION_NOTIFICATION);

    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            intent, 0);

    // Send the notification.
    mNM.notify(peer.getName(), R.string.notify_peer_up, notification); 
}
```